# Positioning the value of a div tag using jquery and css

Tags: jquery, css

In the following function I am passing a parameter pos which contains the position (x & y) value. As you can see I am trying the use these values to place the output of the div tag.  For some reason it's not working.  Can any see if anything I'm doing wrong??

The objective of this function is to display the html in the div at the position you hover...

Currently, it is displaying the output of the hover at the bottom of the web page.

Thanks
Chris

```
featureOver: function(ev,latlng,pos,data)   
{  
    var X = pos.x;  
    var Y = pos.y;  
    alert('X = ' + X + '  ' + 'Y = ' + Y);    
    document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";  
    $("div#over").css("top",  Y + "px");  
    $("div#over").css("left", X + "px");  
    $("div#over").html(data.name);  
},
```

#### HTML CODE

```
<table id=maptable border=2>
<th>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:500px; width:700px; background-color:white; border:1px solid black; "></div>
<div id="over"></div>
</th>
```

Comment: Is the div#over absolutely positioned? Can you post the HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead (using `offset()`):

```
featureOver: function(ev,latlng,pos,data)   
{  
    var X = pos.x;  
    var Y = pos.y;  
    alert('X = ' + X + '  ' + 'Y = ' + Y);    
    document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";  
    $("div#over").offset().top =  Y + "px";  
    $("div#over").offset().left =  X + "px";  
    $("div#over").html(data.name);  
}
```

Comment: Blaster, 
Thanks for the sugggestion... $("div#over").offset({top: Y, left: X});
shifts the output the right of the page.  
What I want is the absolute position

Comment: @Chris: Also add this line in that case: `$("div#over").css('position', 'absolute');`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the position of your div#over. See here for explanation on how the 'top'and 'bottom' properties work in CSS with regards to position:absolute and position:relative.

> For absolutely positioned elements (those with position : absolute or position : fixed), it specifies the distance between the top margin edge of the element and the top edge of its containing block.
>
> For relatively positioned elements (those with position : relative), it specifies the amount the element is moved below its normal position.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/top